# after update from ubuntu 16.04 to 18.04 cannot publish project; getting "eval: Symbol’s value as variable is void: org-enable-table-editor"

Tags: org-table

It appears that I've also lost the ability to use Emacs Org basic table editing commands. For example, when I start a table with a `|` and add the column headings then hit `TAB`, Emacs returns the same message: `Symbol’s value as variable is void: org-enable-table-editor`.

Comment: That might mean that the library (file) where variable `org-enable-table-editor` is defined has not been loaded. Or it might mean that you are trying to evaluate a function symbol with that name as if it were a variable. If it is a function then you invoke it by `(org-enable-table-editor ...)` or by passing that symbol to `funcall` or `apply`.

Comment: `org-enable-table-editor` was removed from the code base a year ago. The new code base that you got with the new version probably does not know about it. The question is why your setup is looking for it: one possibility is that you use it explicitly in one of your initialization files; the other is that you have a "mixed" installation. Are you using the org-mode that comes with emacs? What version of emacs are you running (`M-x emacs-version`)? What version of org-mode (`M-x org-version`)?

Comment: GNU Emacs 25.2.2 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 3.22.21) of 2017-09-22, modified by Debian; Org mode version 9.1.6 (9.1.6-dist @ /home/go/.emacs.d/elpa/org-20160321/). When I load emacs without my initialization file, the table editor commands work. I'll have to dig through my init routine and find what's causing the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The org version (elpa/org-20160321) I was using contained `org-enable-table-editor` and it was 'removed from the code base a year ago'. I tried to remove it using list-packages but due to dependencies it wasn't removed. I read from a comment in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20541322/how-to-remove-installed-elpa-package that it should be fine to delete the elpa package and `package-initialize` will resolve any dependencies.

org table works fine now.